# Django graphene relay restricting queries to objects owned the user

Tags: django, graphene-python

I am doing the graphene tutorial on filtering with relay from: http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/filtering/
where the user is restricted to query objects that they previously created. I am using graphene 2, django 2, and django-filter 1.11.

```
class AnimalFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    # Do case-insensitive lookups on 'name'
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr=['iexact']) #changed this to work

    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ['name', 'genus', 'is_domesticated']

    @property
    def qs(self):
        # The query context can be found in self.request.
        return super(AnimalFilter, self).qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

I am having an inserting the `self.request.user` part, where the user data is loaded. When I do a query like:

```
query {
  allAnimalss {
    edges {
      node {
        id,
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get an error in the query field:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "allAnimals": null
  }
}
```

If I remove the filter it works fine. The tutorial mentioned "owned by the authenticated user (set in context.user)." what does this mean?

I tried adding a get_context_data function to the `views.py`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['user'] = self.request.user
    return context
```

and also changing `self.request.user` to `self.context.user` but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the request and thereby the user via info.context in the resolver method. The docs are not great explaining this, but [here you can see an example](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/authorization/#user-based-queryset-filtering)

```
def resolve_something(self, info, something_id):
    # Here info.context is the django request object
    something = Something.objects.get(something_id)
    if info.context.user.id == something.user_id:
        # The user owns this object!
        return something

    # Return None or raise an exception here maybe since it's not the owner
    return None
```

Comment: The example using resolve_something under the query class works. But the example in "Filtering ID-based node access" does not

Comment: this does not answer the questing coz it was asking how to access user from filter class, this shows accessing user from query