# Django graphene with relay restricting queries access based on ID

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I am trying to restrict single object queries to the user that created them.

**Models.py**

```
class Env(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = TextField()
```

**Schema.py**

```
class EnvNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Env
        filter_fields =  {
            'name': ['iexact'],
            'description': ['exact', 'icontains'],
            }
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


Query(object):
    env = relay.Node.Field(EnvNode)
    all_envs = DjangoFilterConnectionField(EnvNode)
```

I tried adding a resolve query but it [only worked for the "all_env" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916106/django-graphene-relay-restricting-queries-to-objects-owned-the-user) with the filter and did not work for the single object query

```
def resolve_env(self, info):
    env = Env.objects.filter(user = info.context.user.id)
    if env is not None:
        return env
    else:
        return None
```

Also tried adding a class method to the EnvNode as recommended [here under filtering Node based ID access](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/authorization/#user-based-queryset-filtering):

```
@classmethod
def get_node(context, cls, id, info):
    try:
        env =  cls._meta.model.objects.get(id = id)
    except cls._meta.model.DoesNotExist:
        return None

    if context.user == env.user:
        return env
    return None
```

but I got an error:

```
"message": "get_node() missing 1 required positional argument: 'info'",
```

Comment: remove `graphene2` as it is not related to this question. This graphene2 is selenium webdriver extension for arquillian framework

Comment: ok done I thought it was graphene v.2.0 for graphql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the documentation is not correct, also your parameters are not in the correct order for the **get_node** method.

There are only three parameters for the call

- The first one is your **DjangoObjectType** subclass: **EnvNode**
- The second one is a **graphql.execution.base.ResolveInfo** which contains a reference to the context. You can get the user object from there.
- The third one is the actual **id** for the object.

You should write it like this for the restriction to work:

```
@classmethod
def get_node(cls, info, id):
    try:
        env = cls._meta.model.objects.get(id=id, user=info.context.user)

    except cls._meta.model.DoesNotExist:
        return None

    return env
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: works perfect using the test cases. Hopefully they update the graphene docs. Thanks again